# Verificar si existe el registro en la BD

Tags: mysql

Quiero verificar la existencia de un registro antes de insertarlo en la BD. Mi objetivo es:

1.- Verificar la existencia, si existe. Entonces regresar un mensaje que diga "No insertado, porque ya existe"

2.- De lo contrario, insertarlo. Y regresar un mensaje que diga: "Registro insertado"

Todo lo anterior en un solo procedimiento almacenado. A continuación, esto es lo que tengo:
Tabla llamada: actores
Campos:
Nombre      Varchar(50),
FNacimiento DateTime,
LNacimiento Varchar(50),
Nacionalidad  Varchar(50),
FMuerte      DateTime,
LMuerte      Varchar(50),
Los valores IN son los campos anteriores.
El OUT es:  Inserto Varchar(50)

URL del SP: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ceKN8rV-9s8qr39oTvozx4iDLVh9NUtR/view?usp=sharing

Me dice que hay un error en el "IF R" o cerca del mismo y también en los "SET  Inserto" en ambos. ¿Alguien podría decirme por favor, como debería de ser?

Gracias y saludos.

Nota: Ofrezco una disculpa. Tenía una fuerte migraña cuando redacté dicha duda.

Comment: No uses enlaces externos para poner el código de la pregunta, porque se pierden con el tiempo y la pregunta pierde sentido.  He agregado el código encontrado en ese enlace. Puedes [edit] esta pregunta las veces que consideres necesarias.

Comment: **He votado por cerrar tu pregunta** porque no especificas los detalles en la misma, sino que nos mandas a un enlace externo, y tal como te he explicado antes, no debes usar enlaces externos para mostrar el código porque se pierden con el tiempo y la pregunta pierde sentido y no ayudará a nadie más.  No se porque has revertido mis cambios donde ya lo habia puesto por ti, la verdad.

Comment: Léete [ask] y [example] para aprender mejor como funciona este sitio, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partir de este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE actores(
  id_actor int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Nombre      Varchar(50),
  FNacimiento DateTime,
  LNacimiento Varchar(50),
  Nacionalidad  Varchar(50),
  FMuerte      DateTime,
  LMuerte      Varchar(50)
  );
```

Este procedimiento almacenado realiza la función que describes:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE inserta_actor(
    vNombre      Varchar(50),
    vFNacimiento DateTime,
    vLNacimiento Varchar(50),
    vNacionalidad  Varchar(50),
    vFMuerte      DateTime,
    vLMuerte      Varchar(50)  
  ) BEGIN
      DECLARE r bool;
      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO r FROM actores
        WHERE Nombre=vNombre AND FNacimiento=vFNacimiento;
      IF r=0 THEN
        INSERT INTO actores (Nombre, FNacimiento, LNacimiento, Nacionalidad, FMuerte, LMuerte) VALUES
          (vNombre, vFNacimiento, vLNacimiento, vNacionalidad, vFMuerte, vLMuerte);
        SELECT 'Registro insertado' inserta_actor;
      ELSE
        SELECT 'No insertado, porque ya existe' inserta_actor;
      END IF;
    END;
```

Devolviendo *Registro insertado* en la primera llamada y *No insertado, porque ya existe* en la segunda:

```
CALL inserta_actor(
    'Paco Rabal',
    '1926-03-08',
    'Águilas, Murcia, España',
    'Española',
    '2001-08-29',
    'Burdeos, Francia'
  );
```

Entiendo que hagas esto porque, al definir una clave única, el `id_actor` se incrementaría igualmente con las inserciones duplicadas, a pesar de no poder realizarlas.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Buen día, David JP. Funcionó. Muchas gracias, por tu ayuda y por tu tiempo.